# AWS signature in shilogic API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm implementing shiplogic's API into my program and have never worked with AWS authentication

```
<?PHP
$host = "api.shiplogic.com";
$accessKey = 'AKIA55D5DNTBFC3I7BHQ';
$secretKey = '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';
$requestUrl = 'https://api.shiplogic.com';
$uri = '/rates';
$httpRequestMethod = 'POST';

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;

$signature = new SignatureV4('execute-api', 'af-south-1');
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey);
$Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri, ["content- 
type"=>"application/json"], $data);

$sr = $signature->signRequest($Request, $credentials);
```

//var_dump($response);
?>

Now it's a simple piece of code but I'm constantly getting a 403 response.
Am I sending the correct Psr7\request for Authorization?
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers to the request like below:

```
$amzDate = date('Ymd\THis\Z');
$headers = [
'X-Amz-Date'   => $amzDate,
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];
```

After that update the following line from

```
$Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri, ["content-type"=>"application/json"], $data);
```

to

```
$request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri, $headers, $data);
$client = new Client([$requestUrl, 'timeout' => 30]);
$sr = $signature->signRequest($request, $credentials);
$response = $client->send($sr);
```

Lastly, you have not set any value for the $data variable of the request. You can see how this should be formatting by looking under the 'Getting rates' heading at this link https://api-docs.shiplogic.com